# Removing character from the end of a question scrolls up

Tags: bug, ios-app

When using version 1.0.1 of the iOS app I'm experiencing the following issue:

1. Open a question
2. Edit the question
3. Scroll to the bottom of the body to remove some unnecessary "thanks" or "help"
4. Remove line breaks from the end of the question
5. Textview is sometimes scrolling up

I created [a short screencast](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2188000/edit-issue.mp4) which shows the issue.